# How can i auto fill my field and make it non editable in django admin site

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-admin

I need to autopopulate a field in admin site and make foreignkey field non editable with current_user :
**views.py**:

```
def my_view(request):
 obj = model.objects.first()
    response = HttpResponse(file, content_type=' 
  application/vnd.ms-excel',
                                )
    return response
```

**urls.py**:

```
path('temo/fill',views.my_view,name = 'my-view')
```

**models.py**

```
class Model(BaseModel, SingletonModel):
    file = models.FileField(
        upload_to='',
        validators=[FileExtensionValidator([''])]
    )
    person_uploaded = models.ForeignKey(
        'somemodel',
        related_name='s',
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        )
```

**admin.py**:

```
@admin.register(tTemplate)
class TemplateAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('file','person_uploaded',)
    readonly_fields = ('person_uploaded',)

    def save(self, request):
        if not self.id:
            self.person_uploaded = request.user
        super().save()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well to prepopulate a field in django admin its straight forward doing something like so:

```
@admin.register(tTemplate)
class TemplateAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('file','person_uploaded',)
    readonly_fields = ('person_uploaded',)
    

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.user = request.user
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```